# how to avoid the records that are not in database without reindexing solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have a model Ticket which has 4 records. I deleted first 2 records in the database to create a test case as im hitting a bug where there is a mismatch between solr & the database.

```
search = Sunspot.new_search(Ticket) do
  paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)
end

list = search.execute

list.results
```

`list.results` returns `[]` for page 1 and the remaining 2 records for page 2.

Ideally it should have been 1 page with 2 records. is it possible to avoid the records that not in database without re-indexing solr?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".

If you are deleting objects directly from the database and not re-indexing then you're always going to be a in a position where search results don't match what is in the database.

However, if you delete objects through rails then it will update the index for you so that the deleted object is no longer in the index and your search results will reflect what is in the database too.

Comment: I deleted records in the database to create a test case as im hitting a bug where there is a mismatch between solr & the database.

Comment: That's fine as long as you reindex. But if you don't reindex when you delete stuff in the database you're going to run into more problems.